# How to set a threshold for Fork/Join Algorithm in Java?

Tags: java, performance, concurrency, fork-join

How can I figure out an adequate threshold for a Fork/Join Algorithm? For now I arbitrary play with some thresholds and check the result.
But is there any guideline or best-practice how to set a threshold most suitable?

In my example I use an Array with 1_000_000 Elements.

Changing my threshold von 100_000 to:

```
 private final static int THRESHOLD = 10_000;
```

give me more performance. But this is just arbitrary testing.

Can someone help me out? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this is just arbitrary testing.

That is the idea. You experiment on a specific hardware and figure out the correct numbers that give the expected performance.
Usually all the performance measurements are published **along** with the hardware specification these apply.